# How to parse an aspx application form using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, asp.net, parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse some data form an application form using BeautifulSoup in Python.

I am trying to extract some text data in a panel.

```
<div id="Panel4" style="z-index: 102; left: 696px; position: absolute; top: 176px">    

</div>
```

but when I use BeautifulSoup for example;

```
data = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'Panel4'})
```

data  = []

The panel is empty and no data extracted from the site.

How can I read the data included in this label?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the html you have doesn't have div with the id. The `find_all` is correct

Comment: No, sorry. It is a Corp. site

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with the very simple html you have given? (I am not able to) . Try providing a better html that will help reproduce the issue .

Comment: Post an example HTML and your Python code which doesn't do what you expect. The sample what you provided should work.